# Liouville's theorem: How to get an invariant measure?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Liouville's theorem states that the `natural' 2-from is preserved under the Hamiltonian flow. Apparently this leads to an invariant measure $\mu$ as follows

\begin{equation}
d\mu = \frac{d\sigma}{|| \nabla H ||}
\end{equation}
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $d\sigma$ an infinitesimal standard volume element. I have never quite understood how one arrives at this and why you cannot consider the 2-form of the Hamiltonian as a  measure.  The books I have seen up to now seem to label this as trivial but I do not see the connection. Could anybody explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was asked without a satisfactory answer also at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433618/liouvilles-theorem-how-to-get-an-invariant-measure

Comment: I know that was me. I even put a bounty on it to attract attention but it remained unanswered. :(

Comment: In order to define a quantity such as $\|\nabla H\|$, you'd need to have a norm of some kind on (co-)vectors and you'd need to know what the 'standard volume element' is.  However, in the general case of a Hamiltonian on a manifold, you don't have those quantities defined, so I don't know what your formula means.  The usual invariant volume measure $d\mu$ (as a volume form) is more simply defined directly using the $2$-form $\omega$, by the formula $n!\ d\mu = \omega^n$, which doesn't use any metrics or 'standard volume forms'.

Comment: 2-form is not a measure, except in the space of dimension 2. A measure is a volume form, that is an n-form in the space of dimension n.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a derivation of that formula in [Section 7 of Khinchin's book](http://books.google.es/books?id=i6HbVpZclcoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false) and in [Chapter 8 of Pettini's book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/dynamical+systems/book/978-0-387-30892-0).

I hope this helps.